# How to Rebase in Mercurial

Tags: mercurial, repository, atlassian-sourcetree

I've read this [HG Rebasing tutorial](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/RebaseExtension) but still cannot understand how to rebase my repository.

I have changesets in such a sequence:

A - B - C - **D - E**

How to to rebase them in such a sequence ?

A - **D - E** - B - C

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'd need to do two rebases for this.  You need to move D to be a child of A and then move B to be a child of E.

**You should make sure that you have a backup before performing this, just in case it doesn't turn out as you expected.**

First you'd do:

> hg rebase --source D --dest A

Which would give you:

```
A - B - C
  \ D - E
```

Then you'd do:

> hg rebase --source B --dest E

Which would give you the end result that you wanted.

Answer (score 2):

In your case it's **not rebasing**, but rewriting (old) history

For **your task** you can use

- [Histedit](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/HisteditExtension) Extension (part of Mercurial since version 2.3) ([Readme](https://bitbucket.org/durin42/histedit/src/tip/README) cover your use-case)
- [MQ Extension](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/MqExtension) (convert `B - C - D - E` changesets into MQ-patches, reorder, return patches back into changesets state)